# Force the user to watch full youtube video in android?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have made a youtube api demo,In that all goes successfully,Now i want to force the user to watch full video in android using youtube api,SO can anyone please tell me how to do it programatically? What code is needed to do it in android?

**code**

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onInitializationFailure()",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post code for what you're doing at present.

Comment: @Ali-hi thanks for response.Please see my code

Comment: "i want to force the user to watch full video" -- that will require a lot of robot arms controlled by your app, to [hold the user down and pry their eyelids open](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066921/). Note that this may cause user dissatisfaction with your app.

Comment: You can probably intercept the back-key press and do nothing on it while the video is playing. I'm not familiar with the YouTube API and your code doesn't tell me enough to help more.

Comment: It's probably not possible to force the user to watch the full video--but I know if I installed an app on my smart phone that started playing a video and would let me out of it when I wanted, I'd get pretty pissed, pull the battery to get out, uninstall the app, and leave a really negative review.  You may want to re-think forcing the user into anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable only back button but not disable home button.

I will suggest you that please do not disable home and back button because its not a good way. because after doing this you will face few problems.

1. When your video will play then you device is useless. means you can not do any thing.
2. When your video will play then you can not use other application like whats app, calling, and other system application.
3. These things will irritate to user.

So please do not do it.

But If you want then you can make your app as default launcher in android.

Comment: hi..aprreciate your help,but its not what i am looking for,I dont want to disable that back or home buttons,I want to disable seekbar of youtube video (fro youtube api) ,so user must have to see the full video,.